# Prevent iOS Webkit Long Press on Link

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

In an iOS app I'm developing, I show an `UIWebView` to allow the user to upgrade their account. The page contains links to show the user other informations, but you hold your finger on the link, a menu like this will pop up:
[image]

As you can see, it reveals the URL of the page and the action that will be performed, which I do not want the user to see, since I don't want them to be able to copy anything as I disabled the "Copy/Cut/Paste" menu already. How would I go about disabling this menu as well?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Is there any good reason why you want to stop the user from doing this? Seems to me not bothering would just be easier.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think you can disable that popup by setting [the CSS `-webkit-touch-callout` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-_webkit_touch_callout) to `none` on the link.  You would do this by editing the HTML or CSS file you're loading, not using Objective-C.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to both disable the popup **AND** user selection of text on your **ENTIRE HTML PAGE**, use this on the BODY of your web page or global css.

```
  body {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: This works. But if you are concerned about the user altering your CSS then use the programmatic approach suggested by [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15538022/642706). And search for related/duplicate questions and answers.

Comment: You can use `* {` rather than `body {` to cover everything.

Comment: If you want your inputs and textareas to work you need to use `*:not(input,textarea) {}`

Answer (score 17):

What you want to do, as [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff) already stated, is to disable the default contextual menu of `UIWebView`. You can achieve it by adding the following line to `webViewDidFinishLoad:`

```
   [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
```

Answer (score 0):

**No need to tell the browser you have a link and then force it not to behave like one!**

Just remove the `href="void(0)"` completely!

**Your `ontouchend` or `onclick` attributes will still work**.

---

If you want the normal blue/underlined look again, you can add this css:

```
a .originalLink { color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; }
```

This saves a lot of CPU cycles, especially when there are hundreds of links in the page while the user is smooth scrolling.

You can also extend this to regular URLs by using this:

```
<a class="originalLink" onclick="location.href='http://mylink';">Real URL Link</a>
```

Of course your SEO is out the window, but for a *specific* mobile web app situation this can be crucial.

Happy coding!