# Prevent Chrome for iOS from opening "Open in New Tab .. Copy Link URL" pop-up

Tags: ios, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

I use jQuery Mobile to provide the foundation for a web-based application in-which there are a number of input elements - a, input, button, etc.  In Chrome 38.0 on iOS 8, the elements work fine ... unless you touch and hold the element for over 1 second - which will then cause the browser to open a pop-up prompt for "Open in New Tab, Open in New Incognito* Tab, Copy Link URL".

While you can close the pop-up by touching anywhere else on the screen - it is incredibly annoying when using the slider controls () and other elements that you touch and 'hold'.

Any suggestions for how to remove this behavior or disable?

Thanks in-advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to set the -webkit-touch-callout CSS property to 'none' for the element(s) ... or for the body to remove for all elements on the page.

In my case, I added

```
body {-webkit-touch-callout: none;}
```

to remove the 'feature' for the entire page.

THANK YOU to [rob mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff) for his answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9145259/2852050.